# Call from GTalk to Pidgin gives error code 7

Tags: linux, pidgin, google-talk

I have configured Pidgin to connect to my GTalk account. Video and audio are working. I can even make calls from Pidgin to a GTalk account, but not from GTalk to Pidgin.

Whenever I try calling Pidgin I get `The voicechat with "somebody" failed due to an error [Code: 7 Remote: true]`.

I'm running Pidgin on Linux Mint 15.